# pyautogui script doesn't work in zoom app

Tags: python, pyautogui

I have this code that detects an image and click it. There is no mistake in the code but unfortunately the code doesn't work for zoom app and it works just fine in another application.

```
import pyautogui
import time
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False
try:
    x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(r'C:\Users\Owner\VSCODE\codes\images\zoom.png', confidence=0.9)
    pyautogui.click(x, y)
    pyautogui.hotkey('alt', 'f4')
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.hotkey('tab', 'enter')
except TypeError:
    print("A TypeError has been occured!")
```

Comment: Another answer that i figured out to run all script inside vscode as admin is by running the vscode as an admin first or create a shortcut to the vscode and check the run as admin option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some applications block pyautogui. Try to run the script as admin!